# How to fix nodes hostnames too long when deploying helm chart in Gitlab CI

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

### What I'm trying to achieve

Hi, I am currently trying to deploy a postgresql-ha (more specifically bitnami/postgresql-ha) helm chart through a gitlab CI job.

### What I can achieve locally

Locally, when running `helm install postgresql ./postgresql-ha`, I am able to create the chart on my remote Kubernetes Cluster successfully without any error.

`./postgresql-ha` is an unmodified pull of `bitnami/postgresql-ha`.

### What happens when I run it through CI

When I try to run the same command in Gitlab's CI, with a properly set `helm` and `kubectl`, I get this error:

```
Release "postgresql" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: template: postgresql-ha/templates/NOTES.txt:60:4: executing "postgresql-ha/templates/NOTES.txt" at <include "postgresql-ha.validateValues" .>: error calling include: template: postgresql-ha/templates/_helpers.tpl:682:51: executing "postgresql-ha.validateValues" at <fail>: error calling fail: 
VALUES VALIDATION:
postgresql-ha: Nodes hostnames
    PostgreSQL nodes hostnames exceeds the characters limit for Pgpool: 128.
    Consider using a shorter release name or namespace.
```

The first line validates the **kubectl**/**helm** configurations.

### *.gitlab-ci.yml* File

```
##########
# Stages #
##########

stages:
  - deploy charts

########
# Jobs #
########

deploy_postgresql-ha:
  image: dtzar/helm-kubectl:3.0.0
  stage: deploy charts
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - helm upgrade --install postgresql ./postgresql-ha
```

The Kubernetes Cluster was created via Gitlab's Kubernetes Integration tool and is therefore already set up, as per [this Gitlab Documentation page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#deploying-to-a-kubernetes-cluster).

Thanks in advance the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is a bug on pgpool:

*ping probes fail with long hostnames due to small buffer
pgpool calls "ping -q -c3 " and parses the result to ascertain if a host is up or down. Unfortunately it uses a rather small buffer to read the output and the last line of the ping command can get truncated. 
This means that pgpool assumes the host is down.*

https://pgpool.net/mantisbt/print_all_bug_page_word.php?search=&sort=&dir=DESC&type_page=html&export=-1&show_flag=0

Bitnami upgraded the code so now long hostnames are not allowed anymore. Nodehostname is composed on the following components, so you can adjust:

```
$nodeHostname := printf "%s-00.%s.%s.svc.%s:1234" $postgresqlFullname $postgresqlHeadlessServiceName $releaseNamespace $clusterDomain }}
```

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/postgresql-ha/templates/_helpers.tpl